# User account control in windows7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-accounts, uac

It's annoying when I get a popup message saying "do you want the following program to make changes to your computer" for every application I run on my windows.

Is there anyway to change or disable it?

Comment: I'm confused -- You know it's "UAC" and "User Account Control", yet you couldn't just Google "disable UAC on Windows 7" or alike to find out how?  is there some (larger/actual) problem here that we're missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be annoying while installing Some programs, but it is asking for user's security.

Users should know What is UAC (USER ACCOUNT CONTROL)?

- UAC is a security feature of Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8 which helps prevent unauthorized changes to your computer. These changes can be initiated by applications, viruses or other users. User Account Control makes sure these changes are made only with approval from the administrator. If the changes are not approved by the administrator, they are not executed and Windows remains unchanged.

Users can change the settings in UAC
follow these steps in this link [How to set-up UAC](http://techyuga.com/what-is-uac-user-account-control-and-how-to-change-the-uac-level-in-windows/)

[UAC in Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Grg4p.png)

Answer (score 1):

Disable UAC by going to the start menu and type in UAC, the following option will show up:

[image]

At the next screen you can drag the slider up or down, up is more secure, down is less. Completely drag down the slider and UAC will be disabled:

[image]

Or use PowerShell to edit a registry key to disable UAC. (Will take effect after reboot!)

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableLUA -PropertyType DWord -Value 0 -Force
```